# What does the Sixth Sense multiplayer skill do?

Tags: far-cry-3

According to its description, the Sixth Sense skill

> Lets you know when you’ve wandered into an enemy's line of sight.

How exactly does it notify me? I added this skill to some of my loadouts, and I didn't notice anything special when opponents got me from behind, except for a rapid decline in health, followed by death.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an enemy aims at you, an arc appears around your crosshair, pointing in his direction. It looks just like those which appear when someone is shooting at you. But this one is gray and is pulsating.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the HUD shows a thin red line - as opposed to a thick red line, with an arrow - indicating the position of the opponent who can see you.

Comment: No, the line which appears is gray, not red.